# Can't execute drop index in psycopg2 connect in python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to use psycopg2 in python to drop index in postgresql:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database)
cur = connection.cursor()
statement = "DROP INDEX IF EXISTS idx_my_id"
cur.execute(statement)
connection.commit()
```

Same statement can be done in pgAdmin4 in one second. But in python, the execution never finished.

"pg_stat_activity" shows wait_event_type is Lock and wait_event is relation.

What went wrong?

Comment: Is it happening always, or it was a one off? There could have been other transactions that had owned locks on your table.

Comment: You never committed the transaction. After the `cur.execute()` do `connection.commit()`.

Comment: It run smoothly before.  But always happening since last week. I don't know what happened. This statement is the only one Lock transaction. @AnandSowmithiran

Comment: Thanks for mention that, I did commit, I edited the question. And the same code worked before. @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Then `tail` the Postgres log file and see what happens when you run the query.

Comment: Someone is holding that lock which is blocking this DROP.  Figure out who and either do something about it, or wait for it to go away.

Comment: I still can't figure out why. Tail the Postgres log file didn't give me useful info, nothing seems holding the lock. However, after I added codes to terminate some other idle activities, drop index can work normally.

Answer (score 0):

won't fit in comments put it here. maybe because you don't commit your connections?

add this to your code , close all the connections and try again:

```
connection.set_session(autocommit=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for mention that, I did commit, I edited the question. And the same code worked before.